# DataBinding and iNotifyPropertyChanged in Xamarin

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin, inotifypropertychanged

I'm currently making an app using Xamarin Forms. This app will first call a REST service to retrieve the data and display them then store those data into a SQLite Database. I have an update button where if I click on it, it will prompt the REST service once again to retrieve newer data and replace the old data while the app is running. I have tried to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged but the value just wont' change for me. Am I missing anything with my code below? Thanks!

Vitals Object:

```
public class Vitals
{
    public string Height { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Update Method:

```
async void OnUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string tempUser = globalPatient.Username;
        string tempPin = globalPatient.PIN;
        patUpdate = patientManager.GetPatientByUsername (tempUser, tempPin).Result;
        App.PatientDB.DeletePatient(tempID);
        App.PatientDB.AddNewPatient (patUpdate, tempPin);
        DisplayAlert ("Updated", "Your information has been updated!", "OK");
    }
```

VitalsViewModal:

```
    public class VitalsViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public VitalsViewModel (Patient patient)
    {
        vitals = patient.Vitals;

    }
    private List<Vitals> _vitals;

    public List<Vitals> vitals { 
        get {return _vitals; }

        set {
            if (_vitals != value) {
                _vitals = value;
                OnPropertyChanged ("vitals");
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

VitalsView

```
public partial class VitalsView : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    PatientManager patientManager = new PatientManager ();
    Patient globalPatient;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public VitalsView (Patient patientZero)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = new VitalsViewModel (patientZero);
    }
 }
```

Xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="Vitals" ItemsSource="{Binding vitals}" RowHeight="80" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0" Padding="15">
                            <Grid>
                                <Label Font="17" Text="{Binding Height} " FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#449BC4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                                <Label Font="14" Text="{Binding Weight, StringFormat='Weight: {0}'}" FontAttributes="Bold"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Where in the Update method are you modifying the ViewModel?  And can you please show us how you are setting up your data binding?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Jason! I just added the databinding part. Also, how should I approach modifying the ViewModel?

Comment: Your binding looks correct.  But you need to update your ViewModel when you get new data - it won't happen automatically.  Presumably you would set the vitals property to the new collection of data.

Comment: Do you have any code sample of how to do this? I assume it is more than just:
new VitalsViewModel (patUpdate);

Comment: your ViewModel has a public vitals property - just set that to the new dataset you get from your update.

Answer (score 2):

For `vitals` to have a change in Xaml, something must replace the *whole* list, of `List<vitals` with a new list.

Even though the patient changed and its vitals are new from the update, you have bound to an orphaned `patient.vitals` whose `patient` reference is still valid. **Hence no change**.

You need to specifically change the reference of `vitals` away from the old one to the new one.

I suggest this:

```
async void OnUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tempUser = globalPatient.Username;
    string tempPin = globalPatient.PIN;
    patUpdate = patientManager.GetPatientByUsername (tempUser, tempPin).Result;
    App.PatientDB.DeletePatient(tempID);
    App.PatientDB.AddNewPatient (patUpdate, tempPin);

    MyCurrenViewModel.vitals = patUpdate.Vitals; // Replace old vitals

    DisplayAlert ("Updated", "Your information has been updated!", "OK");
}
```

Note In the above example I would create a property named `MyCurrentViewModel` on the page, and when assigning the datacontext I would have

```
public partial class VitalsView : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    VitalsViewModel MyCurrentViewModel { get; set; }

    PatientManager patientManager = new PatientManager ();
    PatientDemo globalPatient;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public VitalsView (Patient patientZero)
    {
    InitializeComponent ();
    //BindingContext = new VitalsViewModel (patientZero);
      BindingContext = MyCurrentViewModel = new VitalsViewModel (patientZero);
    }
 }
```

---

**Code Review Other Errors**

- `OnUpdate` is `async` which is great, but it never `awaits` any method call; hence making all calls to it synchronous in nature and blocking the gui thread waiting on results. Never block a gui thread, the app will appear to freeze.

Comment: Thanks for replying @OmegaMan!
1. That was just old code that was supposed to be commented out. I have re-edited the first page.
2. Thanks for pointing it out! I did notice the freeze of the App when I try to update; possibly doing something about it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As an option, you can use ObservableCollection instead of List.

Comment: I'm also trying to do it that way as well while applying the Fody.PropertyChange nudget.